# Firing the input of a search bar with another button

Tags: jquery, button, input, click

I have a jQuery question: I would like to create the following:I would like when i click a button for my cursor to be on the input of the search bar ready to type. How would i do that? So far i am trying something like this, but it´s not working. Thank you in advance

```
jQuery('.button').on('click', function(){
          jquery('.input').click();
        } )
```

Comment: Use `focus()` instead of `click()`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use focus() function : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus

And you rather use "**$**" instead of using jQuery('.button');

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(){
  $('.input').focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="input">
<button class="button">Enter some text</button>
```